# how to insert all data in table to database using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Below is my code and what I have done so far.

How to insert all data in table to database using ajax after click #orderSave button??

```
<table class="table table-sm table-striped table-hover" id="tbltrs">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbodydata"></tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" id="orderSave" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Process</button>
```

> $("#code").bind('blur keypress',function(event){
> event.preventDefault();     if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.type ==
> 'blur') {         var vals = $('#code').val();        $.ajax({        type: 'POST',
> url: 'check.php',       cache: false,       dataType:"json",        data:{code:
> vals},        success: function(data) {           if(data['ok'] > 0){
> var qty = 1;
> var elems = $('#tbltrs td').filter(function(){
> return $.trim($(this).text()) === data['name'];
> });
> if (elems.length) {
> var qty = parseInt(elems.parent('tr').find('#qty').val()) + 1;
> elems.parent('tr').find('#qty').val(qty);
> }
> else {
> var html = '';
> html += '';
> html += ''+data['product']+'';
> html += ''+data['price']+'';
> html += '';
> $('#tbodydata').prepend(html);
> }
> } else {alert('none');}
> $('#code').val('').focus();
> },
> error:function(err){alert("error"+JSON.stringify(err)); }
> });
> } });

```
$('#orderSave').click(function() {
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'orders.php',
cache: false,
data:............,
success: function(data) {
printWindow = window.open("", "", "height=1, width=1");
printWindow.document.write(data);
printWindow.focus();
printWindow.print();
printWindow.close();
},
error:function(err){alert("error"+JSON.stringify(err)); }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize the form and use the submit event
We use `e.preventDefault()` to not submit

You do need NAME attributes

Also I suggest not to use ID when you append/prepend data

You forget a document.close where you use document.write

Lastly is the  html more readable when you use template literals

```js
$('#tbodydata').prepend(`<tr>
<td class="d-none"><input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="${data['id']}"></td>
<td class="col" name="product">${data(product)}</td>
<td class="col" name="price">${data(price)}</td>
<td class="col"><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" value="${qty}"></td></tr>`);

$("#yourForm").on("submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  const data = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'orders.php',
    cache: false,
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      printWindow = window.open("", "", "height=1, width=1");
      printWindow.document.write(data);
      printWindow.document.close();
      printWindow.focus();
      printWindow.print();
      printWindow.close();
    },
    error: function(err) {
      alert("error" + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: after klick submit, i just get  id and qty from input value (this data show alert :id=2&qty%5B%5D=1&id=1&qty%5B%5D=1), how to  get produt name and price

Comment: sorry you need NAME attributes - see update.

If that still does not work, then update your question and show a [mcve] with relevant HTML

Comment: I have added NAME attributes but no changes, i just get id and qty. and I am still confused about how to input into the mysql database. if #tbodydata many product